# Is it possible to reuse Postman scripts among different Api's test cases?

Tags: postman, newman

We have a situation in our project in which we need to access same methods in different Api test cases. Currently we have copy pasted all these methods in every Api test cases. Is it possible to make these methods in a common method and access from it?

It is possible to store these methods in Global variable. It will work fine in Postman, but it fails while running in Newman.

Comment: Can you please provide your collection and environment variable file? Please also specify the command you use for newman and what error message you get. That may shed some light on the source of the issue.

Comment: Related: collection-scoped scripts are now supported per EOY 2017 - http://blog.getpostman.com/2017/12/13/keep-it-dry-with-collection-and-folder-elements/

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways you can go about this - both of them are "hacky" and by that I mean that they are a byproduct of what Postman allows you to do for other purposes.

1. Create a function and assign it to a variable of the window object - [there's an example in one of the the GitHub threads on the Postman project](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/882#issuecomment-72087086). Quote:

> I've found a hackish workaround is to wrap functions you want to share
>   across test inside a global object. In your first pre request script
>   it would look something like this:

```
// window.{name of wrapper}

window.Utils = {

    percentChange: function(val1, val2) {

        return (((val1 - val2) / val2) * 100).toFixed(2) + '%';

    }

};
```

> In all the tests that are run after you can call that function without
>   needing to put 'window' before it

```
Utils.percentChange(responseTime, newTime);
```

I actually couldn't manage to get this to work, plus it was not viable for my case, because I wanted to create a framework that would be defined only once and then available in any request.

1. A blogger - sorry I cannot find the original blog post right now - suggested an approach which I ultimately used successfully. 
   EDIT: [The almost exact solution is showcased on a blogpost (TIP #5: reuse
   code)](http://blog.getpostman.com/2017/07/28/api-testing-tips-from-a-postman-professional/) on the official Postman blog.

   2.1 Create your reusable code and then store it as an environment or global variable.

   2.2 In your pre-request or tests script, call `eval` on the variable that you defined in the previous step.

**NB**: There is one major issue with either approach - debugging problems or changing the reusable code that you have stored. I struggled with this when I needed to determine where an inconsistent behavior of the reusable code was coming from. Basically, I ended up using console.log a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation!

Comment: Maybe you meant this article: http://blog.getpostman.com/2017/07/28/api-testing-tips-from-a-postman-professional/. It describes your second option in paragraph _TIP #5: reuse code_.

Comment: +Torsen - thanks! I've updated my answer with the link to the blog post.